# rendering controller action in symfony twig

Tags: symfony, twig

Updating deprecated code and i have following problem with render tag

```
> {% render url('_internal_main_navigation', {}) %}
```

transaltes to

```
{{ render(controller('MyBundle::menu', {})) }}
```

Twig does this thing where it appends "Controller" and "Action" to the specified route so That should call `MyBundle/Controller/Controller->menuAction()` but apparently the Controller class is supposed to have some sort of prefix like "MyController" so the twig route can be specified like `'Bundle:My:menu'`
otherwise i get

**Class "MyBundle" noes not exist**

Can i make it work without prefixing the controller?

Comment: what is the problem with telling the controller ? if you don't put it, how the twig render is supposed to find which one it have to call ?

Comment: it should use Controller.php if i specify nothing since Controller is appended to class part of "bundle:class:action" But it does not. I have A Class named just that - Controller.php in which the specified route is defined for menuAction function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to use `render_esi()` which supports routes via `url()` by name aswell and you're set for ESI in the future.

> When using the default render() function (or setting the renderer to
>   inline), Symfony merges the included page content into the main one
>   before sending the response to the client. But if you use the esi
>   renderer (i.e. call render_esi()) and if Symfony detects that it's
>   talking to a gateway cache that supports ESI, it generates an ESI
>   include tag. But if there is no gateway cache or if it does not
>   support ESI, Symfony will just merge the included page content within
>   the main one as it would have done if you had used render().

See [Using ESI in Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/http_cache/esi.html#using-esi-in-symfony)

The following syntax will work in your case:

```
{{ render_esi(url('_internal_main_navigation', {})) }}
```

If you'd like to render by controller-name, you could **turn your controller into a service** and refer to it by the name of the service (i.e. `mybundle_controller`):

```
{{ render_esi(controller('mybundle_controller:menuAction', {})) }}
```